# What is the meaning of "Points" in ICC rankings?

Tags: cricket, ranking

Today I check the [ranking of test cricket](https://www.icc-cricket.com/rankings/mens/team-rankings/test). 
[image: Ranking]
What is the meaning of points, as Sri lanka have third highest point however they are 6<sup>th</sup> ranked team?

Answer (score 3):

The points are the raw accumulation of marks from the ranking system. Since teams only win points, not lose them, teams which have played more matches will tend to have more points, even if they've also lost more matches. This point score is then averaged by dividing through by the number of matches to provide the rating.

As explained by another [page on the site](https://www.icc-cricket.com/about/cricket/icc-rankings/team-rankings), the points gained are are a combination through a mathematical formula of the results of the matches in a series and the relative strength of the teams, so that a team gains more points for beating a high rated team than a low one. This is similar to the Elo rating scheme developed in chess and now being applied to other sports.

[The precise scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICC_Test_Championship#Test_championship_calculations) (from Wikipedia) is

> - Award 1 mark to a team for each match won.
> - Award ½ mark to a team for each match drawn or tied.
> - Award 1 bonus mark to the team winning the series.
> - Award ½ bonus mark to each team if the series is drawn.

The ratings points awarded are then:

**If teams rating difference less than 40:**

(team's own mark) x (opponent's rating+50) 
+
(opponent's mark) x (opponent's rating−50)

**If teams rating difference more than 40:**
The ratings points for the stronger team equals:
(team's own mark) x (team's own rating + 10) 
+
(opponent's mark) x (team's own rating−90)

The ratings points for the weaker team equals:

(team's own mark) x (team's own rating+90) 
+
(opponent's mark) x (team's own rating−10).